# mysql WHERE XXX = ZZZ AND XXX = YYY

Tags: mysql, where-clause, in-clause, where-in

I am new to mySql and am trying to do a filtering query from one column using data from a few other tables.  For example, I can pull a table of names, a table of their marks in the sports classes, and a table of sports.

I can query this database using

`WHERE beta.sport = 'basketball';` pulls all of the beta id's for basketball and effectively all the kids who play basketball.  Now I want to find all the kids who played basketball AND Lacrosee.

```
WHERE beta.sport = 'basketball' AND beta.sport = 'lacrosse';
```

The problem is that the query executes fine, but returns zero results.  I know by manually looking at my data, that there are kids who play basketball and lacrosse.  How do you filter the kids who play both basketball and lacrosse?  OR returns kids that play either lacrosse or basketball.  I only want to return kids that play both and the only access I have to the list of sports is from this one table beta.

TABLE beta

```
beta_id - sport ||
1  - basketball ||
2  - lacrosse ||
3  - football ||
4  - basketball ||
```

Comment: Your query says 'basketball' AND beta.sport = 'lacrosse' but you say in the next sentence "basketball and football." What's the second sport?

Comment: you have lacrosse in that query, did you mean football? Basically you have choices around using AND or OR. You could also look at IN.

Comment: Everyone but Quassnoi missed the point it seems. While ccdpowell did assume wrong when he wrote a simple `AND`, he doesn't want `OR`. Of course Quassnoi's solution assumes that the link tables are present and holds the appropriate info, but it is the only one so far to give a correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    names n
WHERE   (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    beta b
        WHERE   b.sport IN ('basketball', 'lacrosse')
                AND b.name = n.id
        ) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you!  The IN clause was what I was looking for and I did not know how to find it.

Comment: @ccdpowell: `IN` clause is just a handy alias for `sport = 'basketball' OR sport = 'lacrosse'`. It's `COUNT(*) = 2` in a subquery you've actually been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the AND with an OR

AND does not means:

I want all kids who play basketball AND all kids who play lacrosse.

What it means is I want all all kids who play both lacrosse and basketball.

When using OR get used to wrapping your condition in brackets as such

WHERE (beta.sport = 'basketball' OR beta.sport = 'lacrosse')

Answer (score 0):

"WHERE beta.sport = 'basketball' AND beta.sport = 'lacrosse';" this can't return any rows since you're asking for beta.sport to be BOTH basketball and lacrosse... Try OR... WHERE beta.sport = 'basketball' OR beta.sport = 'lacrosse';

You might try a subselect of both...

```
select * from sportsTable 
where itemID in 
(select itemID from sportsTable WHERE beta.sport = 'basketball') 
and itemID in 
(select itemID from sportsTable WHERE beta.sport = 'lacrosse')
```

Comment: I know this is the problem...  If I use OR my results will include kids who play basketball and don't play lacrosse.  I only want results from kids who play BOTH basketball and lacrosse.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE BETA.SPORT = 'BASKETBALL' OR BETA.SPORT = 'LACROSSE'
```

Note de OR, instead of AND.